# Why is the listdir() function part of os module and not os.path?

Tags: python, listdir

`os.path` module seems to be the default module for all path related functions. Yet, the `listdir()` function is part of the `os` module and not `os.path` module, even though it accepts a path as its input. Why has this design decision been made ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I personally find the division between `os` and `os.path` to be a little inconsistent.  According to the documentation, `os.path` should just be an alias to a module that works with paths for a particular platform (i.e., on OS X, Linux, and BSD you'll get `posixpath`, on Windows or ancient Macs you'll get something else).

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os)
Help on module os:

NAME
    os - OS routines for Mac, NT, or Posix depending on what system we're on.
...
>>> help(os.path)
Help on module posixpath:

NAME
    posixpath - Common operations on Posix pathnames.
```

The `listdir` function doesn't operate on the *path* itself, instead it operates on the directory identified by the path.  Most of the functions in `os.path` operate on the actual path and *not* on the filesystem.

This means that many functions in `os.path` are string manipulation functions, and most functions in `os` are IO functions / syscalls.

Examples:

- `os.path.join`, `os.path.dirname`, `os.path.splitext`, are just string manipulation functions.
- `os.listdir`, `os.getcwd`, `os.remove`, `os.stat` are all syscalls, and actually touch the filesystem.

Counterexamples:

- `os.path` has `exists`, `getmtime`, `islink`, and others which are basically wrappers around `os.stat`, and touch the filesystem.  I consider them miscategorized, but others may disagree.

**Fun fact of the day:** You won't find the modules in the top level of the library documentation, but you can actually import the version of `os.path` for any platform without having to actually run on that platform.  This is documented in the documentation for `os.path`,

> However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface:
>
> - `posixpath` for UNIX-style paths
> - `ntpath` for Windows paths
> - `macpath` for old-style MacOS paths
> - `os2emxpath` for OS/2 EMX paths

You can't do the same thing with `os`, it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: good answer. thanks. i agree with you about putting non-string ops in os.path. may be there is another reason.

Comment: @euphoria83: "Not breaking existing code" is a *very* good reason.  Although they could have moved it for Python 3.